# lossless compresion with Imagemagick + if possible reduce bit-depth

Tags: image, imagemagick, compression, tiff, lossless-compression

**I need to convert few hundreds of 190MB and larger tiff  48 bit depth tif files (from scanned photos) to any format to have smallest size possible.  Conversion most be 

a)lossless

b)space efficient 

d)preferably using imagemagick

c) preferably to format which is open source (not propriety format) [like flif](http://flif.info/)
or similar**
**edit as by Mark suggestion on the end of my post I paste the result of identify -verbose Image166.tif**

Long story: 
In order to ARCHIVE my old photo albums  I scanned them with flatbed scanner.  I used the best (reasonable) settings choosing 600dpi and 48 bit color (16 bits per channel). According to imagemagick color space is sRGB Resulted files are 48 bit uncompressed tif that are up 180-230MB each, (each file usually has a few photos inside) .  When I started this process I had  basic knowledge about image formats and basically close to no knowledge about imagemagick. Even though I am using scanners for at least 20 years, non of my previous projects required really archival quality. Quick research in the Web [led me to Flif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Lossless_Image_Format) which seems to have best compression ratio . Trying this time not to reinvent the wheel I tried to use  a ready made software Xnview MP which indeed successfully covenanted to flif files of about one forth of the original tifs. As I have a consumer screens and can not measure optically the difference between the original  and the flif results by Xnview MP I went for imagemagick to check  scientifically the differences between the original and the result. What I found that the result is just 24 bits (even though Xnview is supposed to work up to 32 bit) format. As I rather don't know to measure differences between the images - and understand the significance of the difference. I figured out (I hope it is a right assumption) that I should count the unique numbers of colors in original . So using: identify -format %k filename
I got a few results.  The originals had 35 milion of unique colors while the same converted file by XNview Mp had less then 900K. May be I don't understand something but that's seems for me long way from lossless. 
35 milion colors in the original  (according to my may be not the  best understandig) means roughly the material I scanned scanned should in up to 26 bit.  I'd be fine to have the compressed file 32 bit.  But so far I am unable to do it (when I used the depth switch even the 36 bit depth images had significantly less colors then the originals. I guess some kind algorithm has to be used).    Which bring me to some other fundamental questions:
-Should I assume that in the LOSSLESS compression - I can have the same number of unique colors?
- How I reduce my original 48 bit to lets say 32 bit bearing in mind that there no more then 50 million unique colors in my original tif files.
And some some more technical questions how to convert it to. When I used imagemagick to convert tif to fliff it did converted correctly with exact number of colors but the resulted file has  the same size that the uncompressed tiff Brhhh?
Any pointers to the questions asked above will be Welcome
Thanks

ps. This is my first post in stackoverflow what a great community and resource it is. I was a long time lurking and found solutions in other fields but not in this one.

Btw way I am  I am knowledgeable in audio so if any similarities exist to the audio losses conversion it would be useful to me

```
 Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Mime type: image/tiff
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 4985x7020+0+0
  Resolution: 600x600
  Print size: 8.30833x11.7
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: LSB
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 16-bit
  Channel depth:
    Red: 16-bit
    Green: 16-bit
    Blue: 16-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 34994700
    Red:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 59019 (0.900572)
      mean: 32092.3 (0.489698)
      standard deviation: 10920.2 (0.166631)
      kurtosis: -0.911308
      skewness: 0.168096
      entropy: 0.979004
    Green:
      min: 8374  (0.127779)
      max: 60582 (0.924422)
      mean: 35146.8 (0.536305)
      standard deviation: 9000.88 (0.137345)
      kurtosis: -0.199619
      skewness: 0.0693948
      entropy: 0.966819
    Blue:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 60680 (0.925917)
      mean: 31950.4 (0.487532)
      standard deviation: 9447.85 (0.144165)
      kurtosis: 0.453691
      skewness: -0.238907
      entropy: 0.955565
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 60680 (0.925917)
      mean: 33063.2 (0.504512)
      standard deviation: 9933.94 (0.151582)
      kurtosis: -0.277497
      skewness: -0.0217975
      entropy: 0.967129
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Matte color: grey74
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 4985x7020+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: None
  Orientation: TopLeft
  Properties:
    date:create: 2017-11-04T22:59:11+02:00
    date:modify: 2017-10-17T11:26:16+03:00
    icc:copyright: Copyright (c) 1996 Eastman Kodak Company, All Rights Reserved.
    icc:description: KODAK Srgb
    icc:manufacturer: KODAK
    icc:model: Srgb
    signature: 824aa54c7ce98b5c23ba8bd5116a132cfc56f9ea6f2f16a07d4bdcce63e3b4b8
    tiff:alpha: unspecified
    tiff:endian: lsb
    tiff:photometric: RGB
    tiff:rows-per-strip: 1
  Profiles:
    Profile-icc: 150472 bytes
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 200.439MiB
  Number pixels: 34994700
  Pixels per second: 69989400B
  User time: 0.484u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.500
  Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-7 Q16 x64 2017-10-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Comment: Can you run **ImageMagick**’s `identify -verbose SomeImage.tif` and click `edit` under your question and paste the output?

Comment: Can you try `convert input.tif -compress lzw output.tif` and compare sizes - LZW is lossless compression.

Comment: Thank for example of ImageMagick syntax. But

Comment: If you are on Windows and using v7 of ImageMagick and you did not select the *"Install legacy tools"* option when installing, you may need `magick input.tif -compress lzw output.tif`

Comment: Thank for example of ImageMagick syntax. But b) resulted file is 20% bigger then the original?!  . BTW with 7-zip it is 8.5% smaller A) That's not what I am looking for, I knew t that uncompressed tiff can be compressed.  What I am looking for is much more efficient and sophisticated compression then Tiff. And also to losslessly reduce a bit depth from 48 to about 32. As the original has max 40 million unique colors. Which I understand (may be wrongly ?) should be easily losslessly converted to 32 bit.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot get a 32 bit, 3 channel TIF - you can only get 8 or 16 bits per sample, i.e. 24 or 48 bits per pixel.

Comment: I am green in the subject but you may be incorrect. Actually each time I edited the aforementioned tiff files in MS Paint then by default it will save them as 32 bit - at least according to properties box of Windows Explorer. If I may guess Windows default (native)  support for image files is perhaps 32 bit including for tiff. 
Please provide links sources if I am wrong.

Comment: 32-bit normally means an 8-bit red, 8-bit green, 8-bit blue and 8-bit alpha/transparency channel. If your images are photos/scans, you probably do not want/need an alpha channel.

Comment: Mark is taking about 8 bits per channel (24 or 32 bits per image) or 16 bits per channel (48 or 64 bits per image). If you do not need 16 bits per channel, then add -depth 8 to his command to compress using lzw compression. If you have a fully opaque alpha channel (which is does not appear that you do), you could also add -alpha off to that command.

Comment: I see thanks for the info and teaching.  But if I am thinking correctly it will even more reinforces my idea of more sophisticated compression then tiff like Flif(?) . Bearing in mind that  in my  case there is at most 26 bit of color info.  There has to be format compression that allocate smartly bit depth and then when the image needs to be reconverted to original the format correctly decompresses to 48 bit tif

Comment: What  Mark Setchell and  fmw42 are suggesting in order to achive singficantly smaller files is to use 24 bit depth per image.  I think I got it. But as I understand it will produce lossy compression as my image has  26 bits of color. (right?) Aren't any more advanced format other then tiff??? That will provide a) efficient oppression ratio
b) to have compression completely lossless . Am I missing something ?

Comment: Seriously, JPEG at good quality (95) would be more than enough... At 48Bit and 600 DPI, you are far exceeding the definition and color range of the original pictures. At quality 95 and more there is very little loss, and you'll never notice it, especially if you keep the full chroma.

Comment: A lot of useful info  I am grateful guys. It underlines my need for better understanding of What I am trying to do. Xenoid you comment is specially intriguing.   I understand that the prints I have don't have more then 26 bits of color at least for my scanner sensor. But as ther is no 26 bit depth they are saved in 48. If you could please evaluate (or weblink) on 'exceeding the definition and color range of the original pictures" and on "you'll never notice it, especially if you keep the full chroma"

Comment: continuation  from the comment above.. As a veteran computer guy I am little obsessed with lossless specially in files are meant for archival purposes and the source is analog. And in imagining I have no real experience measuring differences and can't for the moment  internalize what really does the difference between very little loss and lossless means.  It is like understanding  for  mono-sexual space alien difference in  between good sex and great sex.